# My wordpress website is not listed in google

Tags: php, wordpress, search, seo, google-crawlers

**That is my wesbite** [www.shapestudios.de](http://www.shapestudios.de)

I have this problem since more than a year already, i tried every possible thing. 
**Content SEO optimized, media SEO optimized, XML sitemaps submitted to Google webmaster tools.** 
i also use bing webmaster tools, alexa and optimized the url using yoast. meta date is perfect! it just never shows up.

and if i search in google for (**link:shapestudios.de**) the only thing that shows up is a stupid readme text from some plug in but not the actual website.
i have a feeling that it's related to php somehow since the only thing that shows up is text file. but what about the images?

**i'm using a server in Germany by 1&1** .. i have some feeling that the server is blocking google bots from crawling the website. but i can't really tell, as i found no option in the server dashboard to allow or block the bots.

**Can someone please help me!!! :)**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO but is not *specifically* programming related.

Comment: One of those "keeping us on our toes" type of question, in order to see if we're still paying attention and looking out for SEO-related questions? lol

Comment: You're probably better posting this on the WebMasters StackExchange site as this isn't a programming problem.

Comment: turns out the problem is programming related though...

Comment: @Fred-ii- the problem is programming related as i had some extra line in my Php which i didn't see and by removing this line everything started to work, so it has nothing to do with SEO optimization and WebMasters StackExchange in this case. but thank you guys for giving time to read this post.

Comment: Your question's title suggests differently. If you feel that it has been wrongly judged, then you can flag your question and have one of the moderators look at it. They will make that decision.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason it is not being indexed is because of this in head

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
```

That will say not to index the website, remove it and it should start to get indexed/crawled....I think you might need to look into the basics of SEO.

EDIT: To remove that line either:

- Open the header.php file and remove it.

If that line is not on that page then:

- Go to SEttings -> Reading, on that page find the "Site Visibility" section (should be 4th bolded heading  make sure the "Allow search engines to index this site" option is ticked.

Comment: Thank you so much! i removed the line from the Header.php
in my Settings>Reading there is no such option as "Allow search engines to index this site" but the opposite "Discourage search engines from indexing this site" and it has been unchecked the whole time. i should not check it, right?

Comment: Yeah leave that unchecked. It will essentially add a no follow tag and disallow the whole site from being crawled. And if the answer helped you, feel free to mark it as correct so others who have the same problem as you will know how you sooner it.

Comment: Thanks you're a very knowledgeable man. i just have one last question when i try to check my SEO using this website, http://seositecheckup.com/
it says: We cannot access your website in order to perform our analysis! Either is not online, or either our tool is being blocked by your server.
So there is some sort of blocking that i have no idea where it comes from, maybe you know why? 
i'm going to mark it as correct rightnow :)

Comment: It is because of this line " <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow,noodp,noydir"/>", it is taking that site to basically get lost you are coming here.